# KSQL stream created using AVRO as the value format outputs null

Tags: ksqldb

I have data coming in this format

```
{"ROWTIME":1557825832927,"ROWKEY":"null","respondent_id":"noon","machine_data":{"resolution":"1920x1080","region":860}}
```

when I create a stream called COMPLEX like this:

```sql
CREATE STREAM complex WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test-topic-complex-2', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

And then run:

```
SELECT MACHINE_DATA from COMPLEX;
```

it works fine.

Running this:

```sql
SELECT MACHINE_DATA->RESOLUTION from COMPLEX;
```

doesn't work, saying RESOLUTION is not a field in machine data. But it clearly is

I dropped the COMPLEX stream then recreated it and explicitly specified that resolution is a field by creating the stream using this syntax

```
CREATE STREAM COMPLEX (respondent_id VARCHAR, machine_data struct<resolution VARCHAR, region INT>) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test-topic-complex-2', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

after this I can run this query `select MACHINE_DATA->RESOLUTION from COMPLEX;` but I get null as output for resolution

Everything works fine when using JSON as the value format. What gives? Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the Avro schema of the data please?